# Networks simulators

Tags: networking, time, simulator

I need simulate one network where one node send a message to others nodes with known position, and the nodes save the time the message arrived and message send. 
What's the best program to do this?

Comment: Please give us a bit more information.

What do you mean with simulate, what kind of network ? What is the "positon" of a node for you ?

If we´re talking about IP networks or anything similar you might want to check Wireshark and simply setup two laptops sending data from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should tell your question precisely. But in case of you're not familiar with network, it's understandable. I guess NS3 can meet you, you can try it. The website is here:https://www.nsnam.org/.